# GetKeyboardLayout() detects incorrect layout for children

Tags: c#, layout, detection

In my application I use well known piece of code:

```
int WinThreadProcId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), out _ProcessId);
IntPtr KeybLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(WinThreadProcId);

if (KeybLayout.ToString() == "68748313")
{ //russian };

if (KeybLayout.ToString() == "67699721")
{ //english };
```

It works fine for 95% of applications. But it doesn't detect layout in following conditions:
Start Application1 (e.g. Outlook.exe) and then click on http-link, which opens Application2 (IE). In this Application2 layout is always detected as english.

This code correctly works in both IE and Outlook when they launch independently.

Comment: That surely has more to do what kind of web page you visit than the way it got started.  I imagine you didn't have much use for a Cyrillic keyboard layout when you typed this question?  Don't use IntPtr.ToString(), use ToInt32() instead.  Which makes Russian 0x04190419, English 0x04090409.  419 and 409 are the LCIDs.  Only use the low word (& 0xffff), the upper one can have a different value for layout alternatives like Dvorak.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the right reason. Changed to ToInt32 and same behaviour (in most situations my code worked well with cyrillic codepage). Further investigation with "Process monitor" shows that clicking on http-link in Outlook spawns two processes of iexplore, one with 18 threads, another with 22. My software detects one of it. Maybe the problem is with function GetForegroundWindow? I do not see, how can I guess which iexplore is the right one, and which is not.